# DatePicker not updating value after deleting text

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, controls

I have a `DatePicker` element and a button. If I select some date and then delete the text from the `DatePickerTextBox` inside the `DatePicker` and, without losing focus to something else, I click on my `Button`:

The `MyDatePicker.SelecteDate` won't be null, but the `MyDatePicker.Text` will.

How can I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could fix this was Replacing the sealed `DatePickerTextBox` with my custom one, adding a `override` to the `KeyDown` event.

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);

    if (e.Key == Key.Back || e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        if (SelectionLength == Text.Length ||
           (Text.Length == 1 && (SelectionStart == 0 && e.Key == Key.Delete || SelectionStart == 1 && e.Key == Key.Back)))
            Text = null;

            RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(TextChangedEvent));
    }
}
```

Of course, I had to replace the Theme of the `DatePicker` to start using my custom `TextBox`.